# Meteor + Vue runtime-only build

Tags: javascript, meteor, vue.js, server-side-rendering

When using the [Meteor + Vue integration](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor) with server-side rendering, I'm getting the following warning on both client and server:

You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available.

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Is the package doing something wrong? Generally, I'm following [this example project](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor-demo).

Comment: Have you checked this : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html (prod mode) ?

Comment: @82Tuskers this is just in development mode, so I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Isn't Vue meant to give this warn in development mode ?

Comment: I found this useful: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215#issuecomment-238095102

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by just trying to render an empty Vue template. Vue mistakenly interprets this as the template compiler not working properly. Putting some simple code such as the following in the home `.vue` file fixes it:

```
<template>
  <p>foo</p>
</template>
```